# Why was Ellie's body unbroken after she was hit by the truck in Pet Sematary?

Tags: plot-explanation, pet-sematary-2019

How can it be that Ellie's body was unbroken after she was hit by the truck in *Pet Sematary* (2019)? I don't even remember whether there was blood on her body after she was hit by the truck. I mean, it's unreal and this is a movie where creators show us a lot of blood and meat (think of Pascow - he was hit by a car too)...

Comment: New one, in old version (I think that the old one is one of the best movies ever and I'd show it to students if I'd work in institute of cinematography) Ellie wasn't hit, it was the boy (just like in the book and just like almost happened in real life with Stephen's son)

Comment: It's pretty much impossible. Her body would have been in pieces after being hit by a truck. Attribute it to plot convenience.

Comment: Hm... That makes sense... You could answer not in comments))